# How to view a specific ID number using the View function in R?

Tags: r, hierarchical-data, panel-data

I have this very basic question that could not find elsewhere, i have a data with a couple of millions of people who were followed over time. I would like to check using the `View` function the person who has the id number 505233. Or for instance i would like to check people that are in the 2nd and 3rd country specifically excluding the other countries.

I know that this code: `View(df[, c("id", "country", "health")])` gives me back the variables that i am interested in, but what about more details inside the variable itself, could someone please guide me?

```
id  country health
12442   1   8
366453  2   9
366453  2   8
505233  3   8
505233  3   10


structure(list(id = structure(c(12442, 366453, 366453, 505233, 
505233), format.stata = "%9.0g"), country = structure(c(1, 2, 
2, 3, 3), format.stata = "%9.0g"), health = structure(c(8, 9, 
8, 8, 10), format.stata = "%9.0g")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: if the answer has worked for you, would you be able to accept it so that this question can be removed from the "unanswered questions" list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
View(df[df$id == 505233, c("id", "country", "health")])
```

By adding a statement prior to the comma within the square brackets, you can filter the data frame prior to `View`ing it

An alternative using the `tidyverse` would be the following

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  select(id, country, health) %>% 
  filter(id == 505233) %>% 
  View()
```

Some might prefer this if they find it more readable